# Boost.Regex oddity

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

Does anyone have any idea why the following code would output "no match"?

```
  boost::regex r(".*\\.");
  std::string s("app.test");
  if (boost::regex_match(s, r))
    std::cout << "match" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "no match" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe **regex_match()** matches against the entire string. Try **regex_search()** instead.

It would have worked with the following regex:

```
boost::regex r(".*\\..*");
```

and the **regex_match()** function. But again, **regex_search()** is what you're probably looking for.

Comment: +1 - "Determines whether there is an exact match between the regular expression e, and all of the character sequence". See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html

Comment: Though I think he really wants `regex_search()`.

Comment: Indeed, that was it.
I feel kind of stupid now.
Still, thank's for the answer

Comment: @ldx - if it's any consolation, I got confused by the *exact* same thing today, in my case wondering why a `regex_match` was working when it looked like it ought to need a `^` at the beginning and a `$` at the end.

Comment: @Dominic: yes, I can understand the confusion. In Java, String.matches() does exactly the same but PHP's preg_match() for example just looks for an occurrence of the regex similar to Boost's regex_search().